# LG G4 Problem with "camera unfortunately stopped working"

Tags: camera, system-error, lg-g4, camera-flash

Recently my camera on my LG G4 has been having some issues and is not working at all.

When opening the camera app either front or rear there is just a black screen and after a moment the message "camera unfortunately stopped working" and the app is closed. Also I have checked that the flashlight is not working but that must be related to the camera problem I guess.

It is not the first time it happens. Sometime ago I had the same problem for about two weeks but the problem magically solved itself. But know it reappeared when I tried to open the camera through the locked screen menu while having another camera app which might be unrelated but I am not an expert.

I have tried several usual methods to solve the problem:

- Rebooted the phone;
- Deleted Cache (Both camera app and gallery);
- Deleted App Data;
- Tried a third party app;
- Factory Reset;

**Nothing Worked!**

I have know tried to use adb and android studio to see what kind of errors are issued and what I got was this:

```
             --------- beginning of crash
02-03 22:31:11.147 3599-10463/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Camera Handler Thread
                                              Process: com.lge.camera, PID: 3599
                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Media server died.
                                                  at com.lge.camera.device.CameraErrorCallback.onError(CameraErrorCallback.java:32)
                                                  at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1232)
                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
02-03 22:31:11.177 468-812/? E/ThermalEngine: ==== Enter sched_bmhb_cs_gov -> vs_temp = 26 ===
02-03 22:31:11.342 2015-10552/? E/linker: readlink('/proc/self/fd/336') failed: Permission denied [fd=336]
02-03 22:31:11.342 2015-10552/? E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/vendor/lib64/egl/eglSubDriverAndroid.so". Will use given name.
```

I guess the interesting part of the log is this, but there are a lot of errors previously that can trigger failure. So I will post some of those since there are too many too fit them all here:

```
02-03 22:31:05.642 520-10471/? E/mm-camera-isp2:isp_module_start_session:178 session id 1
02-03 22:31:05.645 520-10472/? E/mm-camera: tcc_init: TCC ver.150418
02-03 22:31:05.646 520-10472/? E/mm-camera: q3a_port_init:2727  q3a_port_init: 3A VERSION --> 4.1.0.r2
02-03 22:31:05.647 520-10475/? E/mm-camera: module_faceproc_start_session:1752] session cnt 1
02-03 22:31:05.649 520-10471/? E/mm-camera-isp2: isp_module_start_session:347 num_session_opened 1
02-03 22:31:05.652 520-10472/? E/mm-camera: sensor_laser_init:117  Failure opening sensor library! Error: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/hw/sensors.hal.tof.so" not found
02-03 22:31:05.652 520-10472/? E/mm-camera: gyro_port_init:1216  Failure initializing laser sensor. Error: 4
02-03 22:31:05.652 520-10472/? E/mm-camera: start_accel_sensor: sensor1_open E
02-03 22:31:05.653 520-10472/? E/mm-camera: start_accel_sensor: sensor1_open X, res = 0
02-03 22:31:05.705 520-10469/? E/mm-camera: module_sensor_init_session:1243flash subdev id = 0
02-03 22:31:05.705 468-814/? E/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CLUSTER - Setting CLUSTER[1] to 1689600
02-03 22:31:05.707 520-10473/? E/mm-camera-pp: [INFO] base_module_start_session:91, E, session=1
02-03 22:31:05.707 520-10473/? E/mm-camera-pp: [INFO] base_module_start_session:91, E, session=1
02-03 22:31:05.710 520-10469/? E/mm-camera-sensor: sensor_sdk_util_get_kernel_i2c_addr_type:26Invalid addr_type = 0
02-03 22:31:05.710 520-10469/? E/mm-camera-sensor: sensor_sdk_util_get_kernel_i2c_data_type:40Invalid addr_type = 0
02-03 22:31:05.710 520-10469/? E/mm-camera-sensor: actuator_load_lib:491name=lc898122_claf, mode=camera
02-03 22:31:05.713 520-10469/? E/mm-camera-sensor: actuator_load_lib:491name=lc898122_claf, mode=camcorder
02-03 22:31:05.714 520-10469/? E/mm-camera-sensor: eeprom_do_af_calibration:197turn on Cal af(1)
02-03 22:31:05.714 520-10469/? E/mm-camera-sdk: eeprom_autofocus_calibration_claf:137 KSY Kernel original macro hall : 13600, inf hall : -10080, macro_mecha 21000, vcm_type 65
02-03 22:31:05.714 520-10469/? E/mm-camera-sdk: eeprom_autofocus_calibration_claf:141 KSY AF_algorithm convert macro hall : 350, inf hall : 0
02-03 22:31:05.714 520-10469/? E/mm-camera: ois_init:305start: ois_init
02-03 22:31:05.715 520-10469/? E/mm-camera: ois_init:372done: ois_init
02-03 22:31:05.715 520-10469/? E/mm-camera-sensor: proxy_init:71name = LD_AF
02-03 22:31:05.715 520-10503/? E/mm-camera: ois_thread:201ois thread is running
02-03 22:31:05.715 520-10469/? E/mm-camera-sensor: sensor_proxy_on:151enter
02-03 22:31:05.726 3599-3599/? E/PeerForWman: Watch Library is not activated! Call activate() first.
02-03 22:31:05.733 520-10469/? E/mm-camera-sensor: sensor_proxy_thread_on:198enter
02-03 22:31:05.733 520-10469/? E/mm-camera: module_sensor_init_session:1354tcs_sensor init Enter **
02-03 22:31:05.735 468-814/? E/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CLUSTER - Setting CLUSTER[1] to 1824000
02-03 22:31:05.746 468-814/? E/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CLUSTER - Setting CLUSTER[1] to 1689600
02-03 22:31:05.760 520-10469/? E/mm-camera-sensor: tcs_thread_create:291tcs_thread, thread_id 0
02-03 22:31:05.760 520-10469/? E/mm-camera: module_sensor_start_session:1626SUCCESS
02-03 22:31:05.760 520-520/? E/mm-camera: sensor_get_cur_chromatix_name:2417Error: Load default preview chroamtix
02-03 22:31:05.761 520-520/? E/mm-camera-isp2: isp_resource_query_mod:145 num_isp_preallocate 1 num_session_opened 1 dual_vfe_enabled 0
02-03 22:31:05.761 520-520/? E/mm-camera: module_faceproc_query_mod:1904] Caps ROI 5 scene_mode_cnt 1 HW analysis supported 0
02-03 22:31:05.761 520-520/? E/hdr: module_hdr_lib_query_mod:181] Supported scenemode cnt 2
02-03 22:31:05.761 520-520/? E/mm-camera: isp_port_check_caps_reserve:737 port 0xf4c7f0a0 ide 1000f type 10 dim 0 0
02-03 22:31:05.762 520-520/? E/mm-camera: int_link = 0xf41b76c0
02-03 22:31:05.763 520-520/? E/mm-camera: Interleaved flag is 0, identity 65551 port type 0
02-03 22:31:05.763 520-520/? E/mm-camera: pproc_port_add_modules_to_stream:454] X rc: 1
02-03 22:31:05.769 468-814/? E/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CLUSTER - Setting CLUSTER[1] to 1824000
02-03 22:31:05.769 468-814/? E/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CLUSTER - Setting CLUSTER[1] to 1689600
02-03 22:31:05.778 10487-10487/? E/AppUp4:MvnoProfileEntry: getIdByRule : not matching 
02-03 22:31:05.778 10487-10487/? E/AppUp4:MvnoProfileEntry: getIdByRule : not matching 
02-03 22:31:05.778 10487-10487/? E/AppUp4:MvnoProfileEntry: getIdByRule : not matching 
02-03 22:31:05.778 10487-10487/? E/AppUp4:MvnoProfileEntry: getIdByRule : not matching 
02-03 22:31:05.778 10487-10487/? E/AppUp4:MvnoProfileEntry: getIdByRule : not matching 
02-03 22:31:05.778 10487-10487/? E/AppUp4:MvnoProfileEntry: getIdByRule : not matching 
02-03 22:31:05.778 10487-10487/? E/AppUp4:MvnoProfileEntry: getIdByRule : not matching 
02-03 22:31:05.778 10487-10487/? E/AppUp4:MvnoProfileEntry: getIdByRule : not matching 
02-03 22:31:05.778 10487-10487/? E/AppUp4:MvnoProfileEntry: getIdByRule : not matching 
02-03 22:31:05.778 10487-10487/? E/AppUp4:MvnoProfileEntry: getIdByRule : not matching 
02-03 22:31:05.779 10487-10487/? E/AppUp4:MvnoProfileEntry: getIdByRule : not matching 
02-03 22:31:05.779 10487-10487/? E/AppUp4:MvnoProfileEntry: getIdByRule : not matching 
02-03 22:31:05.779 10487-10487/? E/AppUp4:MvnoProfileEntry: getIdByRule : not matching 
02-03 22:31:05.779 10487-10487/? E/AppUp4:MvnoProfileEntry: getIdByRule : not matching 
02-03 22:31:05.797 450-450/? E/QCameraHWI_Mem: void qcamera::QCameraMemory::traceLogAllocStart(size_t, int, const char*):HeapMemsize 656704
02-03 22:31:05.798 450-450/? E/QCameraHWI_Mem: void qcamera::QCameraMemory::traceLogAllocStart(size_t, int, const char*):Memsize 656704
02-03 22:31:05.798 450-450/? E/QCameraHWI_Mem: void qcamera::QCameraMemory::traceLogAllocEnd(size_t) 656704
02-03 22:31:05.798 450-450/? E/QCameraHWI_Mem: void qcamera::QCameraMemory::traceLogAllocEnd(size_t) 656704
02-03 22:31:05.802 450-450/? E/LGCameraParameters: void qcamera::QCameraParameters::initDefaultParametersEx(): multi_window_af_supported = 1
02-03 22:31:05.802 450-450/? E/LGCameraParameters: createMultiWindowString: (-280,-280,0,0,1),(-140,-420,140,-140,1),(0,-280,280,0,1),(-420,-140,-140,140,1),(-140,-140,140,140,1),(140,-140,420,140,1),(-280,0,0,280,1),(-140,140,140,420,1),(0,0,280,280,1),(-220,-220,220,220,1)
02-03 22:31:05.802 450-450/? E/LGCameraParameters: createMultiWindowString: (720,720,1000,1000,1),(860,580,1140,860,1),(1000,720,1280,1000,1),(580,860,860,1140,1),(860,860,1140,1140,1),(1140,860,1420,1140,1),(720,1000,1000,1420,1),(860,1140,1140,1420,1),(1000,1000,1280,1280,1)
02-03 22:31:05.802 450-450/? E/LGCameraParameters: int32_t qcamera::QCameraParameters::setBeautyLevel(int) : [ARC_BEAUTY] beautylevel = 20
02-03 22:31:05.803 520-10518/? E/mm-camera: sensor_set_frame_rate:1082max fps 30.030001 min fps 2.000000,fixed_frame_rate=0 
02-03 22:31:05.803 520-10518/? E/mm-camera: iface_util_set_hfr: can't find hw stream, only save hfr mode
02-03 22:31:05.807 450-10465/? E/QCameraStateMachine: int32_t qcamera::QCameraStateMachine::procEvtPreviewStoppedState(qcamera::qcamera_sm_evt_enum_t, void*): cannot handle evt(31) in state(0)
02-03 22:31:05.807 450-10465/? E/QCameraStateMachine: int32_t qcamera::QCameraStateMachine::procEvtPreviewStoppedState(qcamera::qcamera_sm_evt_enum_t, void*): cannot handle evt(31) in state(0)
```

Other informations about the phone is that it is not rooted and has no custom ROM installed by me.

I really hope there is someone who can help me with this because this camera would serve me well!

Comment: I am exactly in the same situation with my LG G4. I tried:
- rebooting the phone
- deleting cache
- deleting app data
- doing a factory reset
- removing the camera and installing a brand new one bought in a phone devices store and STILL NOT WORKING. I wonder if you could finally solve the issue. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Turns out that my problem was in the hardware. There was some kind of power supply, in the phone motherboard, that was broken. Basically, the people at the repair shop substituted the motherboard, which is almost the same as a substituting the phone. 
There are a lot of possibilities, but I hope that helps somehow. @nuantagi